# Run 3 python scripts using bash

Tags: python, bash

I want to be able to accomplish the following. 
Run script(1)-->sleep 5-->run script(2)-->sleep 5. This pattern needs to continue for the next 30 minutes before running script(3). Once all 3 scripts are run, they need to loop again in the same fashion.

I have no clue what I'm doing, I know it involves a while loop with a counter, etc. I don't know if this is correct and I don't know where to place script3.py. This is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true;
i=0
until [ i$ -eq 36]
do 
    python script1.py
    sleep 5
    python script2.py
    sleep 5      
    i=$[$i+1]
python script3.py
done
```

Thanks for any feedback!
Damo

Comment: Move `python script3.py` after the `done`

Comment: If you can't write bash scripts then write your code here in Python!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm kind of surprised this question got so many downvotes.  Anyway, this is what you want

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
    begin_time=$(date +%s)
    end_time=$((begin_time + 30*60))
    while [ $(date +%s) -lt $end_time ]
    do
        python script1.py
        sleep 5
        python script2.py
        sleep 5
    done
    python script3.py
 done
```

Comment: Thanks Kurtis, I'm not a programmer and as such have very little experience who asks dumb questions, so I'm not surprised by the downvotes. However, what you suggested works perfectly :)